# Python FFmpeg: Setting VBR and BT.709

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I'm [using this Python library](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) to programmatically generate a short video using an image (.png) as input. The video needs to match the specifications of another video created by someone else.

The key differences between my output and the other are the following (these are the media attributes I desire to have):

- BitRate_Mode: VBR
- <strike>colour_primaries: BT.709</strike> ([Solved via the comment made by Rotem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59329206/python-ffmpeg-setting-vbr-and-bt-709#comment104859690_59329206) - updated my code example to include the solution)

How would I achieve VBR? It was my understanding ProRes 422 HQ natively used unconstrained VBR yet my output specifies CBR.

<strike>Secondly, as can be seen from my code, I'm attempting to conform to BT.709. However, my media information output does not specify this. What am I doing incorrectly?</strike>

Here's my code:

```
    image = ffmpeg.input(input_image, t='00:00:10', framerate='24000/1001', loop='1', probesize='42M')

    output = ffmpeg.output(image, output_video,
    f='mov',
    vcodec='prores_ks',
    vprofile='3',
    pix_fmt='yuv422p10le',
    g='48',
    video_track_timescale='24000',
    movflags='use_metadata_tags',
    timecode='00:00:00:00',
    color_primaries='bt709',
    color_trc='bt709',
    colorspace='bt709',
    qcomp='1',
    # BT.709 issue solved by adding the bsf option as seen via the line below
    bsf='prores_metadata=color_primaries=bt709:color_trc=bt709:colorspace=bt709', 
    vf='scale=in_range=full:in_color_matrix=bt709:out_range=full:out_color_matrix=bt709')

    output.run()
```

Here's the media information produced by my output:

```
{
   "media":{
      "@ref":"Redacted",
      "track":[
         {
            "@type":"General",
            "VideoCount":"1",
            "OtherCount":"1",
            "FileExtension":"mov",
            "Format":"MPEG-4",
            "Format_Profile":"QuickTime",
            "CodecID":"qt  ",
            "CodecID_Version":"0000.02",
            "CodecID_Compatible":"qt  ",
            "FileSize":"196366623",
            "Duration":"10.010",
            "OverallBitRate":"156936362",
            "FrameRate":"23.976",
            "FrameCount":"240",
            "StreamSize":"2463",
            "HeaderSize":"28",
            "DataSize":"196364172",
            "FooterSize":"2423",
            "IsStreamable":"No",
            "File_Created_Date":"UTC 2019-12-13 19:26:37.150",
            "File_Created_Date_Local":"2019-12-13 19:26:37.150",
            "File_Modified_Date":"UTC 2019-12-13 19:27:20.303",
            "File_Modified_Date_Local":"2019-12-13 19:27:20.303"
         },
         {
            "@type":"Video",
            "StreamOrder":"0",
            "ID":"1",
            "Format":"ProRes",
            "Format_Version":"0",
            "Format_Profile":"422 HQ",
            "CodecID":"apch",
            "Duration":"10.010",
            "BitRate_Mode":"CBR",
            "BitRate":"156934237",
            "Width":"1920",
            "Height":"1080",
            "Sampled_Width":"1920",
            "Sampled_Height":"1080",
            "PixelAspectRatio":"1.000",
            "DisplayAspectRatio":"1.778",
            "Rotation":"0.000",
            "FrameRate_Mode":"CFR",
            "FrameRate":"23.976",
            "FrameCount":"240",
            "ColorSpace":"YUV",
            "ChromaSubsampling":"4:2:2",
            "ScanType":"Progressive",
            "Delay":"0.000",
            "StreamSize":"196364160",
            "Encoded_Library":"Lavc",
            "colour_description_present":"Yes",
            "colour_description_present_Source":"Stream",
            "colour_primaries_Source":"Stream",
            "transfer_characteristics_Source":"Stream",
            "matrix_coefficients_Source":"Stream"
         },
         {
            "@type":"Other",
            "StreamOrder":"1",
            "ID":"2",
            "Type":"Time code",
            "Format":"QuickTime TC",
            "Duration":"10.010",
            "FrameRate":"23.976",
            "TimeCode_FirstFrame":"00:00:00:00",
            "TimeCode_Striped":"Yes",
            "Language":"en",
            "Default":"No"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here's the media information spec I'm trying to match:

```
{
   "media":{
      "@ref":"Redacted",
      "track":[
         {
            "@type":"General",
            "VideoCount":"1",
            "OtherCount":"1",
            "FileExtension":"mov",
            "Format":"MPEG-4",
            "Format_Profile":"QuickTime",
            "CodecID":"qt  ",
            "CodecID_Version":"2005.03",
            "CodecID_Compatible":"qt  ",
            "FileSize":"1397430682",
            "Duration":"70.737",
            "OverallBitRate_Mode":"VBR",
            "OverallBitRate":"158042403",
            "FrameRate":"23.976",
            "FrameCount":"1696",
            "StreamSize":"9898",
            "HeaderSize":"28",
            "DataSize":"1397420796",
            "FooterSize":"9858",
            "IsStreamable":"No",
            "Encoded_Date":"UTC 2019-04-29 22:26:32",
            "Tagged_Date":"UTC 2019-04-29 22:26:32",
            "File_Created_Date":"UTC 2019-12-12 16:52:57.215",
            "File_Created_Date_Local":"2019-12-12 16:52:57.215",
            "File_Modified_Date":"UTC 2019-12-12 17:25:58.903",
            "File_Modified_Date_Local":"2019-12-12 17:25:58.903",
            "Encoded_Application":"DVP Factory r561 (2019-04-25), Host: dvp07"
         },
         {
            "@type":"Video",
            "StreamOrder":"0",
            "ID":"1",
            "Format":"ProRes",
            "Format_Version":"0",
            "Format_Profile":"422 HQ",
            "CodecID":"apch",
            "Duration":"70.737",
            "Duration_LastFrame":"-0.000",
            "BitRate_Mode":"VBR",
            "BitRate":"158040381",
            "Width":"1920",
            "Height":"1080",
            "Sampled_Width":"1920",
            "Sampled_Height":"1080",
            "PixelAspectRatio":"1.000",
            "DisplayAspectRatio":"1.778",
            "Rotation":"0.000",
            "FrameRate_Mode":"CFR",
            "FrameRate":"23.976",
            "FrameCount":"1696",
            "ColorSpace":"YUV",
            "ChromaSubsampling":"4:2:2",
            "ScanType":"Progressive",
            "Delay":"0.000",
            "StreamSize":"1397420784",
            "Encoded_Library":"agi0",
            "Language":"en",
            "Encoded_Date":"UTC 2019-04-29 22:26:32",
            "Tagged_Date":"UTC 2019-04-29 22:26:32",
            "colour_description_present":"Yes",
            "colour_description_present_Source":"Container / Stream",
            "colour_primaries":"BT.709",
            "colour_primaries_Source":"Container",
            "colour_primaries_Original_Source":"Stream",
            "transfer_characteristics":"BT.709",
            "transfer_characteristics_Source":"Container",
            "transfer_characteristics_Original_Source":"Stream",
            "matrix_coefficients":"BT.709",
            "matrix_coefficients_Source":"Container / Stream"
         },
         {
            "@type":"Other",
            "StreamOrder":"1",
            "ID":"2",
            "Type":"Time code",
            "Format":"QuickTime TC",
            "Duration":"70.737",
            "FrameRate":"23.976",
            "TimeCode_FirstFrame":"00:00:00:00",
            "TimeCode_Striped":"Yes",
            "Language":"en",
            "extra":{
               "Encoded_Date":"UTC 2019-04-29 22:26:32",
               "Tagged_Date":"UTC 2019-04-29 22:26:32"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't know about the Python library, but for embedding the BT.709 in the metadata, in command line FFmpeg, you should add `-bsf:v prores_metadata=color_primaries=bt709:color_trc=bt709:colorspace=bt709` (the metadata is not automatically added when setting encoder parameters).

Comment: @Rotem I added that as a parameter and it did the trick! I'll update my post. Now I just need to solve the VBR/CBR aspect. Thank you!

Comment: A static image doesn't need VBR. Test a moving input and it will result in `Bit rate mode: Variable`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution [here](https://slhck.info/video/2017/02/24/vbr-settings.html):

Add `q='1'` to the output arguments list:

```
output = ffmpeg.output(image, output_video,
f='mov',
vcodec='prores_ks',
vprofile='3',
q='1',
pix_fmt='yuv422p10le',
g='48',
video_track_timescale='24000',
movflags='use_metadata_tags',
timecode='00:00:00:00',
color_primaries='bt709',
color_trc='bt709',
colorspace='bt709',
qcomp='1',
# BT.709 issue solved by adding the bsf option as seen via the line below
bsf='prores_metadata=color_primaries=bt709:color_trc=bt709:colorspace=bt709', 
vf='scale=in_range=full:in_color_matrix=bt709:out_range=full:out_color_matrix=bt709')
```

---

**Update:**
llogan's comment is correct: "A static image doesn't need VBR".
For multiple images, the `q='1'` flag makes a VBR output.
Without the `q='1'` the output video is CBR.

Tested using a sequence of 5 Tiff images from [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1p-x3hZj-wcgvJsZmjNxXY28WGgisjwFF)

I used the following code for testing:

```
import ffmpeg

input_image = 'seq_01_intro_0200_%04d.tif'

output_video = 'output.mov'

image = ffmpeg.input(input_image, framerate='24000/1001', probesize='42M')

output = ffmpeg.output(image, output_video,
f='mov',
vcodec='prores_ks',
vprofile='3',
pix_fmt='yuv422p10le',
g='48',
q='1',
video_track_timescale='24000',
movflags='use_metadata_tags',
timecode='00:00:00:00',
color_primaries='bt709',
color_trc='bt709',
colorspace='bt709',
qcomp='1',
bsf='prores_metadata=color_primaries=bt709:color_trc=bt709:colorspace=bt709',
vf='scale=in_range=full:in_color_matrix=bt709:out_range=full:out_color_matrix=bt709')

output.run()
```

With `q='1'` (output of Media info):

```
{
"media": {
"@ref": "output.mov",
"track": [
{
"@type": "General",
"VideoCount": "1",
"OtherCount": "1",
"FileExtension": "mov",
"Format": "MPEG-4",
"Format_Profile": "QuickTime",
"CodecID": "qt  ",
"CodecID_Version": "0000.02",
"CodecID_Compatible": "qt  ",
"FileSize": "4121640",
"Duration": "0.209",
"OverallBitRate_Mode": "VBR",
"OverallBitRate": "157766124",
"FrameRate": "23.976",
"FrameCount": "5",
"StreamSize": "1527",
"HeaderSize": "28",
"DataSize": "4120125",
"FooterSize": "1487",
"IsStreamable": "No",
"File_Created_Date": "UTC 2019-12-14 22:14:12.446",
"File_Created_Date_Local": "2019-12-15 00:14:12.446",
"File_Modified_Date": "UTC 2019-12-14 22:16:14.442",
"File_Modified_Date_Local": "2019-12-15 00:16:14.442"
},
{
"@type": "Video",
"StreamOrder": "0",
"ID": "1",
"Format": "ProRes",
"Format_Version": "0",
"Format_Profile": "422 HQ",
"CodecID": "apch",
"Duration": "0.209",
"BitRate_Mode": "VBR",
"BitRate": "158054127",
"Width": "1280",
"Height": "720",
"Sampled_Width": "1280",
"Sampled_Height": "720",
"PixelAspectRatio": "1.000",
"DisplayAspectRatio": "1.778",
"Rotation": "0.000",
"FrameRate_Mode": "CFR",
"FrameRate": "23.976",
"FrameCount": "5",
"ColorSpace": "YUV",
"ChromaSubsampling": "4:2:2",
"ScanType": "Progressive",
"Delay": "0.000",
"StreamSize": "4120113",
"Encoded_Library": "Lavc",
"colour_description_present": "Yes",
"colour_description_present_Source": "Stream",
"colour_primaries": "BT.709",
"colour_primaries_Source": "Stream",
"transfer_characteristics": "BT.709",
"transfer_characteristics_Source": "Stream",
"matrix_coefficients": "BT.709",
"matrix_coefficients_Source": "Stream"
},
{
"@type": "Other",
"StreamOrder": "1",
"ID": "2",
"Type": "Time code",
"Format": "QuickTime TC",
"Duration": "0.209",
"FrameRate": "23.976",
"TimeCode_FirstFrame": "00:00:00:00",
"TimeCode_Striped": "Yes",
"Language": "en",
"Default": "No"
}
]
}
}
```

Without `q='1'`:

```
{
"media": {
"@ref": "output.mov",
"track": [
{
"@type": "General",
"VideoCount": "1",
"OtherCount": "1",
"FileExtension": "mov",
"Format": "MPEG-4",
"Format_Profile": "QuickTime",
"CodecID": "qt  ",
"CodecID_Version": "0000.02",
"CodecID_Compatible": "qt  ",
"FileSize": "2394009",
"Duration": "0.209",
"OverallBitRate": "91636708",
"FrameRate": "23.976",
"FrameCount": "5",
"StreamSize": "1531",
"HeaderSize": "28",
"DataSize": "2392490",
"FooterSize": "1491",
"IsStreamable": "No",
"File_Created_Date": "UTC 2019-12-14 22:14:12.446",
"File_Created_Date_Local": "2019-12-15 00:14:12.446",
"File_Modified_Date": "UTC 2019-12-14 22:22:47.178",
"File_Modified_Date_Local": "2019-12-15 00:22:47.178"
},
{
"@type": "Video",
"StreamOrder": "0",
"ID": "1",
"Format": "ProRes",
"Format_Version": "0",
"Format_Profile": "422 HQ",
"CodecID": "apch",
"Duration": "0.209",
"BitRate_Mode": "CBR",
"BitRate": "91779284",
"Width": "1280",
"Height": "720",
"Sampled_Width": "1280",
"Sampled_Height": "720",
"PixelAspectRatio": "1.000",
"DisplayAspectRatio": "1.778",
"Rotation": "0.000",
"FrameRate_Mode": "CFR",
"FrameRate": "23.976",
"FrameCount": "5",
"ColorSpace": "YUV",
"ChromaSubsampling": "4:2:2",
"ScanType": "Progressive",
"Delay": "0.000",
"StreamSize": "2392478",
"Encoded_Library": "Lavc",
"colour_description_present": "Yes",
"colour_description_present_Source": "Stream",
"colour_primaries": "BT.709",
"colour_primaries_Source": "Stream",
"transfer_characteristics": "BT.709",
"transfer_characteristics_Source": "Stream",
"matrix_coefficients": "BT.709",
"matrix_coefficients_Source": "Stream"
},
{
"@type": "Other",
"StreamOrder": "1",
"ID": "2",
"Type": "Time code",
"Format": "QuickTime TC",
"Duration": "0.209",
"FrameRate": "23.976",
"TimeCode_FirstFrame": "00:00:00:00",
"TimeCode_Striped": "Yes",
"Language": "en",
"Default": "No"
}
]
}
}
```

As you can see with `q='1'`:

> "BitRate_Mode": "VBR"

Without `q='1'`:

> "BitRate_Mode": "CBR",

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work but as [llogan commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59329206/python-ffmpeg-setting-vbr-and-bt-709#comment104861715_59329206), a static image shouldn't require VBR. Thank you for investigating however.

Comment: I can see it as VBR using [Media info](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download) tool. Checked again, and it's true: It's working only for multiple images.

Comment: I downloaded a set of images posted in other question from: [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1p-x3hZj-wcgvJsZmjNxXY28WGgisjwFF), and used `input_image = 'seq_01_intro_0200_%04d.tif'` for testing.

Comment: Yes, well there lies the issue - I'm only using a single static image throughout the entire video. Thanks

Comment: So why is it important if it's VBR or CBR?

Comment: I don't think it is now after reading the feedback. I had a general misunderstanding of the VBR/CBR use cases. I wanted to initially match the spec of the other video, but my video output is static - whilst the other is not. I'm happy to stick to CBR if that's appropriate for my use case. Thanks

Comment: I decided to keep the answer, there is a tiny change it will be helpful for someone else one day...